# PhpSpreadsheet works fine on localhost but not downloading excel file on server, getting some errors

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am using this code

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
     
if(isset($_POST["export"]))
{
  $file = new Spreadsheet();

  $active_sheet = $file->getActiveSheet();

  $active_sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Zone');
  $active_sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Customer');
  $active_sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Competitor');

  $count = 2;

  foreach($all as $row)
  {
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('A' . $count, $row["depot"]);
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('B' . $count, $row["customer"]);
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('C' . $count, $row["name"]);

    $count = $count + 1;
  }
  ob_clean();

  $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($file, $_POST["file_type"]);

  $file_name = 'Competitor Insights.' . strtolower($_POST["file_type"]);

  $writer->save($file_name);

  header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');

  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");

  readfile($file_name);

  unlink($file_name);

  exit;
}
```

Getting this error on server:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\mb_strlen() in
> /home/spectra3/public_html/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/StringHelper.php:451

Comment: check whether the server has `php-mbstring` installed.

Comment: thanks. i enabled php-mbstring and it is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You can install on your server and fixed it.

install sudo apt install [phpVersion]-mbstring

For exmaple:

install sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).